# What does "C" mean in an SVG path?

Tags: svg

```
path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M151.5,85.5c0-36.48,29.52-66,66-66"
```

Can anyone explain `d=""` in detail? I'm able to understand `M` tag but I can't understand what `C` tag is? and the details: `c0-36.48,29.52-66,66-66`

Answer (score 7):

Check [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).  The c is a [curve command](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCurveCommands).

Answer (score 3):

c means the basier curve and then you get three coordinates for B C and D point of the curve the A point is the last point that the line graphic end drawn before calling "c"